# Bind state of the service with UI

Tags: android, service, timer

Lets say I want to implement CountDownTimer in android.
Timer should tick even when activity is closed. So I need service.

Timer UI is in fragment.
It has one button (start/pause).

Timer service should have two states running and paused.

When it's running button label should be "pause" and if it's paused then it should be "resume". You know, like a music player, for example.

It wouldn't be a problem if activity would always run. Then I would just send intent to activity and it would change button label appropriately. You know, like in observer pattern.
But activity could be closed. So how should I update View from the service, if the activity was closed?

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind your activity into the service locally.

I strongly suggest you to go througout this tutorial to get you going:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample

Basically you will have to interact with your service IBinding an interface or the service itself. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot update view of an activity when it is not running.

If your activity is not running, You can use SharedPreferences to save the service status(running/paused). Once you open the Activity read the status and update the button's text.

If your activity is running, you can use Handlers to update the text based on the services status.

Comment: Doesn't look like a clean solution to me. Is  there really no option to implement publisher subscriber pattern with offline messages in android?

Comment: As far as your problem(updating a view from background) is concerned, this is one of the simplest solutions to implement.